# Can I use Distinct with Union All in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, union-all

I am getting values from different tables using `UNION ALL`.
My code is as below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT datei, amount FROM
(
    SELECT datei, amount, 1 AS identification FROM income
    UNION ALL
    SELECT datee, amount, 2 AS identification FROM expense
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date, amount, 3 AS identification FROM others
) t
ORDER BY `datei` ASC
```

But I want it to be `distinct` on date.
So how can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For 2 same dates there will be 2 amounts which amount will be picked to show single record?

Comment: first INCOME amount will be shown

Comment: *"But I want it to be distinct on date."* -- `DISTINCT` is a synonym of [`DISTINCTROW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) and that's how the things work. *"distinct on date"* doesn't make any sense. Which row to choose when there are two or more rows with the same value on the `date` field?

Comment: last row will be chosen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get single amount for date you can use following query

```
SELECT  datei,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(amount),',',1) amount
FROM (
    SELECT datei,amount, 1 AS identification FROM income
    UNION ALL
    SELECT datee,amount, 2 AS identification FROM expense
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE,amount, 3 AS identification FROM others
) t
GROUP BY datei
ORDER BY `datei` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT datei, sum(amount)
FROM
(
    SELECT datei, amount, 1 AS identification FROM income
    UNION ALL
    SELECT datee, amount, 2 AS identification FROM expense
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date, amount, 3 AS identification FROM others
) t
GROUP BY datei
ORDER BY datei ASC
```